# LyX: Проверка правописания?

Tags: latex, lyx

В LyX, по-видимому, проверкой правописания можно пользоваться двумя способами.
Не подскажите, как?

Comment: Попробуйте обратиться в техническую поддержку продукта. Здесь обычно задают вопросы по программам, связанным с программированием (IDE, редакторы кода) или системным администрированием (СУБД, анализаторы трафика)

Comment: Во-первых, я не знаю языка: вряд ли они будут разговаривать с первым попавшимся человеком, не умеющем толком сформулировать свою мысль на их родном языке, во-вторых, если тут задаются вопросы, связанные с редакторами кода, то почему здесь нельзя задать вопрос про [процессор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LyX) в конечном счете того же кода? (Запись текста в файл `.tex`, `.lyx` - это то же самое кодирование вводимого текста).

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не связан с проблемами программирования или системного администрирования.

Comment: @Grek79, автопереводчики в помощь: [Яндекс Переводчик](https://translate.yandex.ru/?lang=ru-en) или [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ru&tl=en)

Comment: Так что, можно, нет, писать ответ?

Comment: @mymedia на Мета  ТС поднимал вопрос, по поводу, оффтопик или нет, и по поводу метки также. Вроде бы одобрили

Comment: @Grek79 пиши пожалуйста более развернутые вопросы, глянь в [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) как лучше оформлять вопрос и подвязывай по возможности это всё как-то к программированию или системному администрированию, а то уж очень граничит с оффтопиком

Comment: Честно говоря, переформулировка заголовка темы,ИМХО, не совсем практична с точки зрения облегчения отыскания его поисковыми системами. Я так и думал, что структура заголовков всех моих тем будет такая: LyX: "то, о чем я хочу писать, лучше пункт меню или команда, про которые я хочу в конечном итоге рассказать". Именно в таком виде человеку, скорее всего, придет в голову написать запрос в браузере. В частности, для данной функции. В настройках LyX есть такие места: i.postimg.cc/yYLQgNKw/1.jpg и i.postimg.cc/23NznxnS/2.jpg

Comment: Так что сам Бог велел включить в название темы словосочетание "Проверка орфография", Ну, и "LyX" нужно. А вы взяли и весь мой расчет уничтожили.

Comment: Да, еще. >а то уж очень граничит с оффтопиком Насколько я знаю, оффтоп - это сообщение (часть сообщения), не относящееся к основному предмету обсуждение темы. Так как может быть оффтопом первое сообщение (всё сообщение!) темы, описывающее предмет обсуждения ентой самой темы?

Comment: В связи с высказанной мной задумкой можно вернуть теме прежнее название?

Comment: Скажите, тут нет "Ответить на собственный вопрос" потому что вопрос закрыт?

Comment: @Grek79 да. . .

Comment: @Grek79, при создании вопроса есть галочка "Ответить на собственный вопрос", если ее отметить, появится поле для ответа, и можно будет опубликовать ответ **одновременно** с вопросом